# How to do a simple image swap with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I'm learning Javascript for my Intro to Programming Concepts class and I decided to make a simple photography portfolio site for my final project. I'm making the gallery now and I'm not sure how swap images.

This is what it looks like (cut off but you get the idea):
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhHX5.png)

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">
 <div>
  <img src="images/nature/1.jpg">
  <br>
  <div class="gallery">
    <img src="images/nature/2.jpg">
    <img src="images/nature/3.jpg">
    <img src="images/nature/4.jpg">
    <img src="images/nature/5.jpg">
    <img src="images/wedding/1.jpg">
    <img src="images/wedding/2.jpg">
    <img src="images/wedding/3.jpg">
    <img src="images/wedding/5.jpg">
    <img src="images/wedding/4.jpg">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

How do I make it so when you click an img from .gallery it swaps places with the first img (images/nature/1.jpg)?

Comment: What JavaScript have you tried?

Comment: First thing you need to do is figure out how to reach the image in javascript ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean when you click on swipe div, no matter what pic is showing in `.gallery` will be replaced by 1.jpg.

If that is the case, you can bind onclick event on `.gallery`, by getting `event object`, you can get access to the source dom element that triggers the event.

Then you can use javascript to change src attribute.

```
var gallery = document.querySelector('.gallery');
gallery.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var targetImg = e.target;
    targetImg.src = 'images/nature/1.jpg';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should take whatever image is currently in the first image and swap it out with the one that is clicked:

```
var firstImage = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0],
    gallery = document.getElementsByClassName('gallery')[0];

gallery.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var target = e.target;

  if (target.tagName == "IMG") {
    var newImage = target.src;
    target.src = firstImage.src;
    firstImage.src = newImage;
  }
});
```

You can test it out here:  https://jsfiddle.net/hxhe90qL/6/

After enough clicking around, however, the images will probably be all out of order.  You could change it to only swap the first image by replacing the code inside the `if` statement to:

```
firstImage.src = target.src;
```